# Functional equations satisfied by the modular function $\lambda$

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-equations, complex-geometry, modular-forms

Let $\lambda(\tau)=\dfrac{e_3(\tau)-e_2(\tau)}{e_1(\tau)-e_2(\tau)}$, where $e_1=\wp(\frac{1}{2})$, $e_2=\wp(\frac{\tau}{2})$, and $e_3=\wp(\frac{1+\tau}{2})$. (Please see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1756461/regarding-the-weight-of-the-given-modular-form) question for the complete set-up.)

There are $5$ functional equations satisfied by $\lambda$, three of them being consequences of the "basic" two, namely $\lambda(\tau+1)=\frac{\lambda(\tau)}{\lambda(\tau)-1}$ and $\lambda(-1/\tau)=1-\lambda(\tau)$.

In a couse which I followed some time ago those two were proved using some specific results and notation from earlier lectures. (The main result I mean is that there exists a holomorphic automorphism of $\mathbb C$ mapping $L(\tau_1)$ to $L(\tau_2)$ iff there exists a biholomorphism between the complex tori corresponding to those two lattices; and the proof of the functional equations was based heavily on explicit forms of those maps and notation intoduced along the way.) I was wondering whether there is a kind of independent proof of these relations?

Comment: $\wp_{\mathbb{Z}+\tau \mathbb{Z}}(z) = \sum_{n,m} \frac{1}{(z-n-m\tau)^2}-\frac{1}{(n+m\tau)^2}$ Thus $\wp_{\mathbb{Z}-1/\tau \mathbb{Z}}(z)=?$ From this you'll get $\lambda(\tau+2)$ and $\lambda(-1/\tau)$ immediately. as well as $\lambda(\tau+1)$.

Comment: Thank you, it turned out to be very easy. I got $\wp_{-1/\tau}=\tau^2\wp_\tau(z\tau)$, and the second functional equation follows easily. It is also obvious that $\wp_{\tau+1}(z)=\wp_\tau(z)$, and the first equation follows.